# Extracted text from HTML is blank

Tags: scrapy, css-selectors

I am a beginner at scrapy and wish to extract the price (15.00) from the `HTML` below

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
  <bdi>
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>
    15.00
  </bdi>
</span>
```

This code that I have written gives me the entire `HTML`.

```
    def parse(self,response):
        for product in response.css('div.astra-shop-summary-wrap'):
            yield{
                'oprice': product.css('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').get()
            }
```

As per what i understand if I add `::text` to `span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount` it should give me the desired output however it gives me a blank output.

Any idea as to how to correctly do this? and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try
span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount>bdi

Comment: so upvote and mark check my answer please

Comment: so that others can find it useful and correct